# My table is not getting sorted with Jquery's tablesorter plugin

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, tablesorter

I have created a simple contact manager using backbone.js and I have stored  my data using  Jquery saveit and loadit plugins and displayed the data in tables.
Now I want to sort the table by first name ,so I used jquery's tablesorter plugin,
but it's not working I have read all the documentation of tablesorter but  no success.
this is what I wrote in render function of view

```
$("tlist").tablesorter({ 

    // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
        sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
});
```

My table looks like this

```text
 first name      last name     phoneno  
--------------------------------------------
 Nitish          pakhare       4545454  
 Ashish          sharma        45454
```

Comment: @Nithish does the above code come inside the render function of the view?

Comment: yes i wrote it inside view's render function

Comment: `$("tlist")` is not a valid selector make it `$(".tlist")` if it's a class or `$("#tlist")` if it's an ID.

Comment: yeah thnks ,Iwas stupid to not check the syntax.

Comment: The problem is solved,thnks for the help

Comment: @Nitish You might ask him to put this into answer and mark that as answer

Comment: @Joy: You should put that down as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("tlist")` is not a valid selector make it `$(".tlist")` if it's a class or `$("#tlist")` if it's an ID.